# OS X - List all active sockets

Tags: scanning, network, tcp, socks

I'm looking for a simple command that will list ***ALL*** currently active and/or otherwise bound TCP & UDP sockets, corresponding port numbers and their respective states (i.e. ESTABLISHED, LISTEN, WAIT, etc.)

Sort of like a ***reverse*** `nmap` scan is what I'm going for here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `netstat`'s manual page:

> The netstat command symbolically displays the contents of various network-related data structures.  There are a
>        number of output formats, depending on the options for the information presented.  **The first form of the command
>        displays a list of active sockets for each protocol.**

```
pse@Mithos:~$ netstat
Active Internet connections
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)    
tcp4       0      0  localhost.8228         localhost.52662        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  localhost.52662        localhost.8228         ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.30.52661     stackoverflow.co.https ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  localhost.8228         localhost.52656        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  localhost.52656        localhost.8228         ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  localhost.8228         localhost.52651        ESTABLISHED
...
```

Comment: This gives `syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: @clankill3r how are you calling `netstat`?

Comment: `man netstat(1)`

Comment: @clankill3r Try `man netstat` for the manual page, `netstat` for the command itself.

Answer (score 10):

Another way to do it is to use `lsof` benefiting it shows the process that owns the sockets. Either combined with `grep`:

```
sudo lsof -n -i | grep -e LISTEN -e ESTABLISHED
```

(just use `-e WAIT` accordingly if you need it specifically), or *with its own filtering* based on TCP socket states:

```
sudo lsof -n -i -s TCP:LISTEN,ESTABLISHED
```

I know certain versions of `netstat` show process with the `-b` switch, but not the OSX/BSD one apparently...

Comment: You need to run this as root (i.e. use `sudo`) to see other users' processes. Also, you can skip the `grep` by telling `lsof` you only want sockets in those states: `sudo lsof -niTCP -sTCP:LISTEN,ESTABLISHED`

Comment: Yeah sorry. Root access is required to see all ports. Good catch!